# Migration API Read

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration

I know there is a API for reading meta data from files in SharePoint with the new Migration API read. But is there an API for migration of large amount of data from SharePoint to Fileshares, blobs or servers?

Comment: Hello, so you want data to move out from SharePoint online to file shares? Do you want to keep the metadata or concerned about just files?

Comment: Yes. Move files away from SharePoint. Not the metadata.

Comment: How much data are we talking about? I am guessing it's not as easy as using One drive sync client and then move it to the file shares. You can use PowerShell to automate the download task, here is one such example to connect to SharePoint online document library and download all files with folder structure: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/documents-from-SharePoint-99e58875#content
You can extend this to read your library locations and download then in batch. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: We are talking millions of dcouments. So needs to go through Migration API or something similar. CSOM will be throttled like...